# Make Some Homophonous Noise

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, pattern, unsolved-mysteries, homophone

## How many homophones can be used in a single sentence?

Rules:

1. Sentences must be English. (no foreign words, like *see* & *si* (*si* is "yes", in Spanish)
2. Sentences can not be a *setup* to list homophones. (i.e. "Here is a list of all homophones: accessary, accessory; [...]; you'll, yule." While grammatically correct, it is not what a **puzzle** is defined as: **a game**, toy, or problem **designed to test ingenuity** or knowledge.)
3. Sentences must follow rules of grammar according to: https://www.grammarcheck.net/editor/ (deep check)
4. No numbers, only words for numbers. (i.e. *4* and *four* are the same thing, only use **four**, not 4).
5. Each time a homophone group is used in the sentence, the score increases by +1 for the first time a word from that group used. There are no additional points for words repeated unless context changes. (i.e. the word can be used as both a noun and a verb, and the word's context uses them this way. "He **rose** to pick a **rose**." Would score +2; "There are **too** many people **to** count coming **to** the club." Would only score +2, not +3.)
6. Homophone groups with 3 or more words in them only need **to** use **two** of the 3+ words, but an additional +1 will be given for each additional homophone of the group used. (i.e. that sentence would get a +2 score for **two** and **to**, but if **too** was used as well, it would get a +3)
7. Any Top Score ties go to the one who answered first.

[Note: There are a finite number of homophones in the English language, and thus, a finite number of sentences that can be composed using combinations of them, so we are looking to find the single sentence that can contain the most. The answer to this question is currently unknown.]

---

**Current Top Score:** 15
**The Sentence:**

They're there to show their wordplay is too much fun for only two to four people, so come to the fore and join in the play by making a play or go buy a room at an inn.

**Homophone groups**: they're, there, their (+3); too, to, two (+3); for, four, fore (+3); play, play (+2); by, buy (+2); in, inn (+2).

---

#### Note - Please use this structure in Answers:

Sentence:
[your sentence here]
(i.e His nose knows he planted the rose in one of two rows.
Homophone groups:
(rose; rows (+2);knows, nose (+2); etc..)

Score: (i.e. 4)

Comment: This appears to be an open-ended question with rule based on "lucidity", which depends on the listener. It is therefore both subjectively valid and [open-ended](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles), both of which are reasons it is off-topic for this site.

Comment: @Deusovi kind of harsh. Was that a group decision? I get some people might not want to participate but if that is just you making a decision for everyone I don't see why people couldn't decide for themselves. If I removed the lucidity rule, would that fix the problem with it for you or are you just anti-open-ended questions?

Comment: Since this is a completely open-ended question with subjective criteria, it is *off topic for this site* as explained in that meta post. This is not about me "not liking it". The question is not a question to be answered or a puzzle, but a game. It is therefore not on-topic for this site.

Comment: @Deusovi I read the discussions. I am not taking it persona or stating this as an insult, but you *are* biased against open-ended puzzles. You also said that "games" are not "puzzles" in one of the discussions. They are. This is a great game to test ingenuity... if I can edit the rules. I agree with the "lucidity" issue. The grammar rule is sufficient.

Comment: puzzle (noun) a game, toy, or problem designed to test ingenuity or knowledge.

https://www.google.com/search?q=define+puzzle

Comment: @Deusovi ok. I made some edits to the rules, let me know if they focus it better and eliminate the subjectivity issue.

Comment: It's a nice challenge for an open-ended question, but unfortunately open-ended questions were declared off-topic as Deusovi says. Also, linking to a dictionary's definition of "puzzle" doesn't really prove anything with regard to the scope of this website.

Comment: @Randal'Thor oh.. I thought they just had to be good open-ended questions. I must not have read all the discussion around this subject. The link to the definition was just to establish what a puzzle is. So this site uses a different definition of that word? Very puzzling. ;-)

Comment: @Deusovi is it just the tag at this point? Would removing the open-ended tag solve the problem? "Good questions for this site have a limited number of objectively correct answers." There is a limited number of homophones in the English language and a limit on the number that could be used in a single sentence. I don't know what that limit is, but that is why I asked the question.

Comment: No, it's not just the tag. This is an open-ended question as defined by the above meta post, and so it is off-topic for this site. (What counts as an "English sentence" is inherently vague; you can put a lot of words together using semicolons, or the word "and", or do any number of other things. There is no way to get everyone to agree on what a grammatically valid or sensical English sentence is. But this is only *PART* of the problem. The question is not one that can be easily fixed by adding more constraints; it is fundamentally off-topic.)

Comment: https://www.grammarcheck.net/editor/ deals with the grammar issue.

Comment: "Too to two new knew few rue do dew there they're." Test things like that there. They get flagged.

Comment: The "Deep Check" option is free, but they charge for a correction.

Answer (score 1):

Here is mine to kick it off:

#### Sentence:

They're there to show their wordplay is too much fun for only two to four people, so come to the fore and join in the play by making a play or go buy a room at an inn.

#### Homophone groups:

they're, there, their (+3); too, to, two (+3); for, four, fore (+3); play, play (+2); by, buy (+2); in, inn(+2).

#### Score: 15

[Note: The word 'play' is being used in 2 different contexts: a noun & a verb.]